# How to wait for async HTTP requests to return values on Angular 4?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, typescript, asynchronous

I have some "cards" that I want to get information for them on an Angular service, the problem is that I get this information with http requests on an API, and I want the return to happen after ALL requests are completed.

#### cards.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {CardsService} from './cards.service';

import 'easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'cards',
  templateUrl: './cards.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cards.scss']
})
// TODO: move easypiechart to component
export class Cards {

  public charts: any;

  constructor(private _cardsService: CardsService) {
    this.charts = this._cardsService.getData();
  }
}
```

#### cards.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BaThemeConfigProvider, colorHelper} from '../../../theme';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class CardsService {
  _meterCountURL = 'http://localhost:8080/meter/count';
  _cardMeter;
  _cardConsumption;
  constructor(private _baConfig:BaThemeConfigProvider, private http: Http) {
  }

  getData() {
    let pieColor = this._baConfig.get().colors.custom.dashboardPieChart;

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')});

    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get(this._meterCountURL, {headers: headers}).map((response) => {response.json()['data'];}),
      this.http.get(this._meterCountURL, {headers: headers}).map((response) => {response.json()['data'];})
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this._cardMeter = data[0];
        this._cardConsumption = data[1];
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );

    return [
        color: pieColor,
        description: 'Consumo do mês atual',
        stats: 0 || this._cardConsumption,
        icon: 'ion-flash',
      }, {
        color: pieColor,
        description: 'Número de unidades ativas',
        stats: 0 || this._cardMeter,
        icon: 'ion-ios-speedometer',
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

When It runs, where it should have an Integer, it appears:

> [object Object].

If I try to put the return statement INSIDE the subscribe function, 'cards.component.ts' gives me the following error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'.

How can I return the card information after the http requests finishes correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning the observable in your `getData()` method, then subscribe in your component. This way the component knows when the observable completes (in the subscribe method).

```
// card.service.ts
getData() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(...);
}

// cards.component.ts
this._cardsService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.charts = ...;
});
```